# Sort a dictionary by value with tuples

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I want to sort my dictionary by values, with tuples. The sort would be by the first element of each tuple.

Here is my dictionary :

```
{(5, 10, 1, 0): [(960, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_04_b82a9acee5c2312484edd30e845caee2_1'), (1050, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_05_5c0ac7ab7cab8393a8b00cb0662d0e0f_1'), (240, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_02_2e48a1a040e9296a7f2cdd7171fe95ea_1'), (210, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_02_48bca44bcabb4b2354d5aa0ace25d57e_1'), (0, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_01_2baa028a3b00cfa8a02aa381169b783b_1'), (450, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_03_858ca6d9d9327b16282755574f9aecd6_1'), (900, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_04_fc277debaf1f012d08c2fc39f4aaf7f0_1'), (810, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_04_7b3469908d76f9c91e38f7b95eda8445_1'), (870, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_04_574fdcd2ebac8c0f05de300c080dcbcd_1'), (570, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_03_acfd45aba4470131a3e925edd7b0643a_1'), (780, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_04_bb79691a80711deb103e6fccfde25e1b_1'), (1170, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_05_58b70919bafea452ed9ea1c18a70dddb_1'), (600, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_03_245d74df690d22ef7a8b34b56860cc12_1'), (0, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_06_a958cc0553d9d3bb225313f2e5e9afe0_1'), (660, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_03_9513652713c604ea98231291337484fe_1'), (690, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_03_a964cef1820c7476a9eb775e3b302005_1'), (150, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_02_ef18e5c430aea54d6c1ae2f819ab2836_1'), (30, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_01_d105af31e66e27f995a3f4b7929c9f6a_1'), (1260, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_05_decfbd0e2c621b34eae59216ec9a08c6_1'), (480, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_03_b54218883d35c4c8a21ca11d56518b0d_1'), (90, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_01_db395a3c5e61ce93d3dd43e2a7a0d495_1'), (1110, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_05_6a05f8b452602afbf6498cf4f2f770c2_1'), (1350, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_06_5331ec214429b97a110e584ba833696e_1'), (120, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_01_1ff6f938cb6cbe8b6f3e60a4ddb8a08f_1'), (1230, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_05_86137661a09950769b321e2b77fb0f64_1'), (630, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_03_3f9a150574e51d5659683e052e769de0_1'), (750, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_04_1582a187b0da5d4bcfdc9bc4aea2b970_1'), (330, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_02_813ad80a2c163fdf6af95a50e72bad74_1'), (990, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_04_797e3c44b82d5130bbc1ded31845b45f_1'), (1200, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_05_659b9ba1dae5f4615f519a48dc0375b7_1'), (720, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_03_95c322ee04f4a79c196efa4b83a695f1_1'), (930, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_04_e2b5fc29b4a7d4e9701ea3f68574f43a_1'), (420, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_02_0b3289c80f6d66de5c2d3c051a854ec5_1'), (390, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_02_3d4904d2cb5bd3e06395706360c94cae_1'), (840, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_04_1beda58704953952696761de06d7262f_1'), (1290, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_05_2493e39e864869b5a0e91a2008ed95e9_1'), (510, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_03_f1459e4d1665a7d0a4b526e5c77a9e41_1'), (60, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_01_e166f74139546afc2cc5116e72d33244_1'), (1020, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_05_cc5c90d1c34b31d1e093c40b949ca153_1'), (1080, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_05_885e82ecac64bd89b27443438846bba0_1'), (1320, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_05_00f676920f4c488193e73684697ef5d4_1'), (1140, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_05_b098cbca1338db0d1c0c6b643629549d_1'), (180, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_02_02675d728ba2678fff5bec8611e5c4e3_1'), (270, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_02_5896de6695b93a2390b8d5f5b00f2414_1'), (540, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_03_350c6e8d1d1cbb9ecbd43f8f88b8f5b7_1'), (360, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_02_2c7380fd0471af9958fce29c2797a01f_1'), (300, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_02_14e42d62ccd5b4e95c3694c3f0ccb91a_1')], (5, 10, 1, 2): [(0, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_11_55bfcf180b79ddd3ba53b10294ee9feb_1')], (5, 10, 1, 1): [(0, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_11_c39ad5a91b9556dd76699f4b0c1d9674_1')]}
```

I've tried many methods like :

```
sorted_x = sorted(x.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

or :

```
sorted_x = sorted(x.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1])
```

But none of them worked... Can someone help me ?

EDIT : my output needs to be :

```
{(5, 10, 1, 0): [(0, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_01_2baa028a3b00cfa8a02aa381169b783b_1'), (30, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_01_d105af31e66e27f995a3f4b7929c9f6a_1') ... }
```

Comment: maybe have to use `sorted(x[(5, 10, 1, 0)], ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this dictionary-comprehension:

```
d = {(5, 10, 1, 0): [(960, '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_04_b82a9acee5c2312484edd30e845caee2_1'),...]
d1 = {k:sorted(v, key=lambda x: x[0]) for k,v in d.items()}
```

**Output** :

```
{(5, 10, 1, 0): [(0,
                  '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_01_2baa028a3b00cfa8a02aa381169b783b_1'),
                 (0,
                  '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_06_a958cc0553d9d3bb225313f2e5e9afe0_1'),
                 (30,
                  '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_01_d105af31e66e27f995a3f4b7929c9f6a_1'),
                 (60,
                  '/tata/2019-06-27_11_17_01_e166f74139546afc2cc5116e72d33244_1'),
   ...}
```